# update row of table by value of other row in other table by same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, join

I want update table `contracts` by values in `contracts_history` table where both of id is same of other.

I write this code but not work :

```
function recover_contract($contract_id)
{
$sql = "UPDATE contracts SET ROW = (SELECT * FROM contracts_history WHERE contracts.ID = contracts_history.ID)";
$result = $this->update($sql);
return $result;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I use this code

```
update 
contracts a, 
contracts_history b 
set 
a.name_surname=b.name_surname
```

But my table has 64 structure
isn't any solution for copy all data with out type all of structure?
must this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contracts_history` SELECT * FROM `contracts` 
        WHERE id='$contract_id'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is as follows:

```
update 
    contracts a, 
    contracts_history b 
set 
    a.col1=b.col1, 
    a.col2=b.col2 
where 
    a.id=b.id
```

on that note though, you have no ID specified in the query, which means it will update *ALL* the rows that are in the history table. You can add  condition like this:

```
update 
    contracts a, 
    contracts_history b 
set 
    a.col1=b.col1, 
    a.col2=b.col2 
where 
    a.id=b.id 
    and a.id=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this as your Query?

```
$sql = "UPDATE contracts c 
        LEFT JOIN contracts_history h ON c.ID = h.ID 
        SET WHAT_YOU_WANT";
```

Comment: hi @Giez, i just formatted your code to make it more clear :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you are updating to one column, your `subquery` should only return one value.

Try,

```
UPDATE contracts 
SET ROW = (SELECT columnName
           FROM contracts_history 
           WHERE contracts.ID = contracts_history.ID
           LIMIT 1)
```

or using by using `JOIN`

```
UPDATE contracts a
       INNER JOIN contracts_history b
       ON a.ID = b.ID
SET    a.row = b.columnName
```

**UPDATE 1**

ok. so here it goes, on the first type which is updating using value from subquery, I added `LIMIT` at the select statement because you cannot update one column with multiple values on it or else you will get an error message. on the second part which is joining both tables,  `a.ID = b.ID` is the relationship of both tables. This defines how the tables are related with each other. `SET    a.row = b.columnName`, `columnName` is the source of the value which is basically on the table `contracts_history`.

Comment: @user1659079 i just updated the answer. if it is ok, can you add the schema of the tables and may a little sample records on it?

Comment: @user1659079 it could be both. actually your feedback is not clear, you are always saying `not working`. Why? Can you be more specific? I'm trying to help you :D

Comment: @user1659079 does your code generate an error? what was it saying?

Comment: oh
yes
i hame a file by this code :
<?php
require("NewsSql.inc.php");
$db = new NewsSQL($DBName);
error_reporting(-1);
$contract_id = 39;
$result = $db->recover_contract("$contract_id");
echo $result;
?>

and in newsSql.php i have : 
   function recover_contract($contract_id)
   {
      $sql = "
UPDATE contracts 
SET ROW = (SELECT columnName
           FROM contracts_history 
           WHERE contracts.ID = contracts_history.ID
           LIMIT 1)

";
      $result = $this->update($sql);
      return $result;
   }

its must be work and i realy cand underestand why its not work

Comment: you should change this column `columnName` to the name of your column in your tables. it just shows an example in the answer above, can you post the schema of your tables?

Comment: my table have 64 structures :|
i replace `columnName`  with `*` and don't have any respond
and replace with `name_surname` that a structure of my tables but this is not work too